# trigger javascript when user type some text

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there was a way when the user types something then the javascript will run. 
example: 
when the user types 'username' then run javascript. 
but it was not in a textbox or textarea.

Comment: If the browser tab has a focus, yes it's easy, look for "onkeyup". If not, of course you can't.

Comment: http://www.syntacticsugr.com/23-javascript/sugr_cubes/81-globally-capture-key-press-events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `onkeyup`

```
var arr = [];
document.onkeyup = KeyPressed;  
function KeyPressed( e )  {
var key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
arr.push(key);
if(arr.join("") == "USERNAME")
alert("Get in");
else
console.log(arr);
}
```

try this in your console.

Comment: can you change 'alert()' into show .GIF, i have tried but still cant, i dont know where is my fault. thanks.

Comment: can you paste your code, in the question so that I can see the error

Comment: now I know my mistakes
I'm not adding   `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"> </ script>`  thanks @aelor

Comment: why the alert just once, i mean when i type again, it isnt show, but need to reload it. can you make it not just once, but can be used many times without reloading page.